# How to block subdomains under my main domain

Tags: google-search, subdomain, robots.txt

I want all my subdomains to not be indexed under my domain, that means when I search in Google for example.com to not appear in index test.example.com, but when I search test.example.com to be indexed.

Is it possible to add a Code in domain.com `robots.txt` to not index the subdomains when search on google site:example.com?

Now if I search on Google site:example.com Google shows results for all my sub-domains, but I want results only for example.com and not test.example.com.

Only when I search site:test.example.com I want the results for the sub-domain.

Comment: This is confusing. Can you clarify this some??

Comment: Aren't you referring to the Google search results, rather than the actual "index" status of your subdomains? This would also make any reference to "robots.txt" irrelevant?

Answer (score 2):

In Google, to do a `site:` search on the main domain (eg. `example.com`), but exclude the subdomain `test` from the search results you would use the search:

```
site:example.com -site:test.example.com
```

You would need to do this for each subdomain you wish to exclude from the results.

> Is it possible to add a Code in domain.com `robots.txt` to not index the subdomains when search on google `site:example.com`?

However, you can't influence this behaviour in your server-side code, it is simply how Google's `site:` operator works. If your subdomains are indexed at all then they could be returned by a `site:example.com` search.

The only way to prevent your subdomain from appearing in the search results is to not have it indexed at all, which is not your intention.

Comment: Oh! Now I get it!!

Comment: I think he want to enforce it from the server (either on `example.com` or on `test.example.com`). A user who only knows about `example.com` and does a search for `site:example.com` should not even learn about the existence of `test.example.com`. At least that's how I read the question.

Comment: @kasperd Yes, I think you're right - I've updated my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this with an X-Robots-Tag HTTP header on any subdomains I create. Setting something like `Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"` in the Apache VHOST or .htaccess file, or `add_header X-Robots-Tag noindex;` in Nginx, will tell search engines not to index anything on that subdomain.

This will have to be done for each subdomain you create, but it's not so much of an extra effort.

Comment: Although they do appear to want the subdomain indexed, but only to appear in the SERPs for a `site:subdomain.example.com` search, but not included in a `site:example.com` search.